# Change event not triggering in extjs4.1 using refs in controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Change event is not triggering in extjs4.1 using refs in controller. I have implemented the following code. I have used combo box id cmbMarketRegion.

Can anybody correct me? If there is anything missing let me know.

This is my View combo box

```
{
    xtype:'combo',
    id:'cmbMarketRegion',
    minWidth:50,
    minHeight:30,
    displayField:'marketRegionName',
    valueField:'marketRegionId'                                                 
}
```

**In Controller**

```
{
        ref: '#cmbMarketRegion',
}

  ], 

   init: function() {
    this.control({
        'cmbMarketRegion': {
            change: 'valueChange'
        }
    });

    }, 


valueChange:function(combo, ewVal, oldVal,optionsVal) {
    alert("hai");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the xtype 'cmbMarketRegion', not id. 
Try something like this:

```
this.control({
    'combo[id="cmbMarketRegion"]': {
        change: this.valueChange,
        scope: this
    }
});
```

or, because id is unique:

```
this.control({
    '[id="cmbMarketRegion"]': {
        change: this.valueChange,
        scope: this
    }
});
```

Try to don't use id attribute, it's global.

Comment: You can use simpler selectors: `#cmbMarketRegion`. This will also match components with `itemId` property set to that value; the advantage here is that `itemId` does not have to be globally unique.